# UINavigationBar (which is embedded in UIImagePickerController) background colour was not updating this issue happening only in iOS13

Tags: ios

I am trying to change UINavigationBar(which is embedded in UIImagePickerController) background colour but not working on iOS13

Code sample: 1 Which is working fine in iOS12 but same code not working in iOS13.

```
_photoPicker = new UIImagePickerController();

_photoPicker.SourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;

_photoPicker.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;

_photoPicker.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Yellow;

_photoPicker.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.Yellow;

 AND Tried below code also for iOS 13
```

Code Sample : 2

```
var navBarAppearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance();

navBarAppearance.ConfigureWithOpaqueBackground();

_photoPicker.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;

navBarAppearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

_photoPicker.NavigationBar.StandardAppearance = navBarAppearance;

_photoPicker.NavigationBar.ScrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance;
```

but it's not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNZZ8.png)

Comment: Still no solution for this? I debugged the view hierarchy and also noticed that the navigation bar is missing in iOS 13 but is showing in iOS 12.